# Do horses spawn in desert biomes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a survival world that is just a giant desert, and I found saddles and horse armors. I was wondering if I could find any horses in the desert.

Answer (score 2):

In the wild, no.

According to [Minecraft wikia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse):

> Horses spawn in **plains** and **savannas** in herds of 2–6.

However, villages naturally generate with stables and animal pens containing horses.